# BASH: show find all files but not last 2 newest

Tags: bash, find, backups

I have a list of files one time list can contain:

```
1489247450-filename1
1489248450-filename2
1489249450-filename3
1489249550-filename4
```

and another time:

```
1489249450-filename3
1489249550-filename4
```

and another time:

```
1489245450-filename1
1489246450-filename2
1489247450-filename3
1489248450-filename4
1489249450-filename5
1489249550-filename6
```

The list is created by:

```
find ./ -type f -name *filename* -exec stat --format="%X-%n" {} \; | sort
```

**I would like to choose all of the files but not the 2 newest.**

I can build a script which could count all files and subtract 2 and after that do `| head`. But is there much more simple way to do this?

I would like to remove old files in only condition that there is a 2 newest.

I don't want to use ctime because files are not created in regular time.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Comment: Nothing useful :(

Comment: That's surprising. Also, `ctime` is not file creation time, it's when a file was last changed. Maybe more useful than `atime`, considering that [`atime` isn't even updated immediately in some distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8842/118235).

Comment: Modificationtime is mtime. The atime parameter very depends of the FS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result was really simple.

If You would like to list all files but the newest 3 you can do:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*605*" -exec stat --format="%X-%n" {} \; | sort | head -n -3
```

The head -n -3 is the main thing!!

Comment: `sort | head -n -3` does the same as `sort -r | tail +3`. Also, if you want to make this more robust and deal with filenames containing newlines, you can use `--printf="%X-%n\0" {} \; | sort -z | headn -zn -3` to separate with the null character instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is in the right order:

```
find ./ -type f -name *filename* -exec stat --format="%X-%n" {} \; | sort | tail +3
```

Otherwise:

```
find ./ -type f -name *filename* -exec stat --format="%X-%n" {} \; | sort -r | tail +3
```

Comment: You don't know how many files there is in result. So it's not useful.

Comment: I don't get your point. The question asked for, well, something not quite clearly explained, but which seems to want all-but-two. This statement produces all-but-two. The fact that you don't know how many files all-but-two are is immaterial. But if you wanted to know, you could just pipe it to wc -l.

Comment: Ah, I see by your answer below that you probably mistook "tail +3" for "tail -3" and didn't try it out before objecting. Yeah -- "tail -3" would only work if there were five files (which would lead to a valid objection that "you don't know how many files there are"). But that's not the case here with "tail +3".